# Delete row and delete table lock oracle

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two query

1.`delete from x;`

2.`delete from x where y='a'`

what type of lock does oracle 11 g provide to above query?

And suppose we iterate the below query in a program

`delete from x where y='$a'`

Let a have list of number 1,2,3,4..
Now if the same program is called from 2 server will 1 server delete 1,3... and other server will delete 2,4...?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/server.1111/e25789/consist.htm

Comment: Are both queries in different transactions?

Comment: both query different transaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Since there is no where clause, all rows will be locked in the table for that user session. 2) only those rows matching the where clause will be locked. Oracle uses row level locking by setting a lock bit in the data block for that row.

Unless and until a commit is issued - no other session will see these deletions. Oracle will use rollback information - created for each separate delete (or any DML operation) statement to provide a read consistent view to any other session. Meaning: the other sessions will see the table *without* the deletions. Once the rows are locked - other sessions will be prevented from issuing a delete against those rows and the user will be blocked, waiting for those rows to be committed or rolled back. You can test this with two sqlplus sessions.

If you want to know more about locks, look at Tom Kyte's excellent book, Expert Oracle DB Architecture.

Yes, two different sessions can delete **different sets** of rows. Oracle does not do full table locking by default (it does lock the table during DML to prevent structural changes to that table while changes are pending), so one session will not block another.

Answer (score -1):

No problem. You can delete non existing records. But you mustn't forget commit transaction.